# Failure to connect to archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: proxy, software-sources

My computer cannot download anything via Ubuntu software center because it fails to connect to archive.ubuntu.com.

I happen to have figured out the problem. It tries to use proxy to connect to Internet, how do I stop this?

Comment: Are you sure, you are connected to the internet (unless of course you are using the same computer to post this question)?

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of problem I faced few days before. I figured it out there was some network changes. Make sure that the method use to connect with network will be selected as "none". You can get this option in network proxy interface in network settings.